# SVN - copy from repository to the live server

Tags: svn

How can I copy all files from the repository to the live server (without the parent folder)?

I have repository like this:

```
Dev_Folder
    ..
    .htaccess
    app/
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    files/
    index.php
    logs/
    robots.txt
    test.php
    vendor/
```

When I use **svn checkout host/Dev_Folder/ ** the directory is being copied to the designeted folder (I am doing the checkout in the folder in which I want files to be copied). Is there a way just to copy the files?

Comment: `svn checkout` will get a working copy, which you probably don't want. Take a look at [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html), it will get the files / folders but without the `.svn` folders.

Comment: I used **svn export** but it still coping the folder o.O

Comment: You might want to show the command line you are using (do you specify `.` for the destination?)

Comment: Nope, I didn't use **.**. It is working with the dot (didn't know about that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn checkout host/Dev_Folder/ .` ?

Comment: I would suggest `export` instead of `checkout`, but should work otherwise.

Comment: @crashmstr yes, but let's do one step at a time.